# Given pandas dataframe highlight one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to highlight one of the columns to say blue. I have tried doing this:

```
df['column'] = df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightblue' if x.name == 'column' else '' for i in x])
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.style.apply

method
```

Because of this you do not want to be assigning the column to be equal to it. The style.apply is done in place, so remove the assignment and just use

```py
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightblue' if x.name == 'column'
                          else '' for i in x])
```

and it will style the column in place.

Comment: For some reason it didnt color the column :(

Comment: `x.name == 'column'` is important, make sure you have a column in the DataFrame with that value. If you still can't get it to work then share more info please!

Answer (score 1):

This solution also works.

```
def highlight(s):
    same = s == df['column']
    return ['background-color: lightblue' if x else '' for x in same] 

df.style.apply(highlight)
```

Comment: I am using VS Code and it still does not work but it does work with jupyter notebook :(

Comment: Check this link to work with Jupiter within VS code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support